# Any existing solution to implement "opening hours" in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm making a website for a client who wants to be able to change then opening hours
for each of his different stores. Is there an existing solution  for this type of problem with Django ?

Comment: How are you currently modelling the stores?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What do you mean? Seems pretty simple. Adjust according to your weekday order. And if you like, add validation. But people should be smart enough to not need validation for that sort of stuff.

```
HOUR_OF_DAY_24 = [(i,i) for i in range(1,25)]

WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]

class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey("StoreModel")
    weekday_from = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS, unique=True)
    weekday_to = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    from_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_24)
    to_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_24)

    def get_weekday_from_display(self):
        return WEEKDAYS[self.weekday_from]

    def get_weekday_to_display(self):
        return WEEKDAYS[self.weekday_to]

class SpecialDays(models.Model):
    holiday_date = models.DateField()
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    from_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_24, null=True, blank=True)
    to_hour = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=HOUR_OF_DAY_24, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: instead of writing get_weekday_from and get_weekday_to methods, you could use get_weekday_from_display and get_weekday_to_display, as mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: in this solution it is not possible to have different hours in different days of the week, maybe this is the key of the problem

Comment: @julio.alegria: Why is it not possible? It was made so it would be possible to have regular intervals, one or several days. And then you can add in you SpecialDays on top of that. I don't really see the challenge here. Nor why this arnoud briche is asking this question without following up on it with some actual substance.

Comment: I think you want to do unique_together on store and weekday_from, instead of on just weekday_from.

Comment: Maybe it is reasonable to use 'PositiveSmallIntegerField' instant of 'IntegerField'