# Django - Objects for business hours

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to modelize business hours for a week of a company. Here is my attempt:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='company_logos')
    mon_start = models.TimeField()
    mon_end = models.TimeField()
    tue_start = models.TimeField()
    tue_end = models.TimeField()
    wed_start = models.TimeField()
    wed_end = models.TimeField()
    thu_start = models.TimeField()
    thu_end = models.TimeField()
    fri_start = models.TimeField()
    fri_end = models.TimeField()
    sat_start = models.TimeField()
    sat_end = models.TimeField()
    sun_start = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    sun_end = models.TimeField(blank=True)
```

Does this seem correct ?

Isn't there a more dynamic way to define it ?

Can I easily validate each day (on a form) ?

Comment: I think this a good idea - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8128427/830941

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any existing solution to implement "opening hours" in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128143/any-existing-solution-to-implement-opening-hours-in-django)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From @lyapun suggestion, an acceptable solution for me would be:

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    logo = models.FileField(
        upload_to='company_logos'
    )



class OpeningHours(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        Company
    )
    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        choices=WEEKDAYS,
        unique=True
    )
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()
```

Comment: I think you want to do unique_together on store and weekday, instead of on just weekday.

Comment: That's right, it's actually `unique_together=(weekday, store)`

Comment: Will a [1]DurationField() in Django 1.8 be better alternative to to_hour. Considering sometimes the store may close after 12AM? This way closing time on anyday is from_hour + duration on a specific day? Is this a good approach? [1]:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield

Comment: For business that close at noon, you must not set unique=true