# Business Opening hours in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to add Business hours for a clinic and I've looked into this [Any existing solution to implement "opening hours" in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128143/any-existing-solution-to-implement-opening-hours-in-django) but it's not right for me. Because this one assumes you'll have same set of hours for all the weekdays and same set of hours for special days. Whereas, I want to have different opening hours for individual days. Moreover, I want to have more than 1 entry for an individual day. For instance, a clinic on Sunday runs from 8:30 am - 12:00 pm and opens again from 4:30 pm - 10 pm.

I want to be able to add this from the admin panel, similar to Yelp

[image]

Comment: So ... what's the problem?

Comment: You need to customize the admin templates, take a look at [Django Docs: Custom template options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IMHO the solution from the link is doing almost exactly what you want.  Just customize it a bit:

```
WEEKDAYS = [
  (1, _("Monday")),
  (2, _("Tuesday")),
  (3, _("Wednesday")),
  (4, _("Thursday")),
  (5, _("Friday")),
  (6, _("Saturday")),
  (7, _("Sunday")),
]

class OpeningHours(models.Model):

    weekday = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    from_hour = models.TimeField()
    to_hour = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('weekday', 'from_hour')
        unique_together = ('weekday', 'from_hour', 'to_hour')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s: %s - %s' % (self.get_weekday_display(),
                                 self.from_hour, self.to_hour)
```

Comment: I still can't add more than 1 entry for a single day.

Comment: Why not?  `weekday` field is not unique so you can add any number of `OpeninHours` records for a single day.

Comment: How would you call this in Forms.py?